# correct way of registering broadcast receiver android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In my android application, I am registering multiple broadcast receiver that includes: WiFi, Screen and Activity. The app is running smoothly on Moto g and Samsung G3 but its stopped sensing Screen on/off, Wifi connect/disconnect and Activity events on another phone after three days of smooth execution. Since app is on user phone, i dont know the model/make. Other than event sensing, the usual location sensing is working fine (which is scheduled after every 10 mins). Any ideas what could be wrong? Otherwise, on my test devices it still runs fine (testing for more then 2 weeks). For reference, below is the code for screen sensor only. Also, I tried to register receiver in onstartcommand, but it didn't work on my test devices (See the commented part in screenService)

MainActivity:

```
Intent intentscreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScreenService.class);
startService(intentscreen);
```

ScreenService:

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver mybroadcast = new ScreenReceiver();
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        /* if (intent!=null)
        {
            IntentFilter screenStateFilter = new IntentFilter();
            screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
            screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
            registerReceiver(mybroadcast, screenStateFilter);
        }*/
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate (){
        super.onCreate();

        IntentFilter screenStateFilter = new IntentFilter();
        screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        registerReceiver(mybroadcast, screenStateFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(mybroadcast);
     }
}
```

ScreenReceiver:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
               Log.i("Check","Screen went OFF");
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                Log.i("Check","Screen went ON");

       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

These `BroadcastReceivers` have to be registered dynamically

```
android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
```

EDIT:
MainActivity.java
    package com.kishore_kumar.stackoverflow;

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

BroadcastReceiver mybroadcast;
IntentFilter screenStateFilter;
static boolean alreadyListening = false; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mybroadcast = new ScreenBroadcastReceiver();
    screenStateFilter = new IntentFilter();
    screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
If (!alreadyListening)
{
    registerReceiver(mybroadcast, screenStateFilter);
alreadyListening = true;
}


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

ScreenBroadcastReceiver.java

```
package com.kishore_kumar.stackoverflow;


import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;


public class ScreenBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        Log.e("Check", "Screen went OFF");
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        Log.e("Check","Screen went ON");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you see the code above and see if there is any bug? The app is running fine on Samsung S3, Moto g, Nexus but stop receiving screen/wifi/activity event (after three smooth days) on samsung note edge..Any suggestion?

Comment: Why don't you try using `intent.getStringExtra` instead of `intent.getAction`. It worked for me on an previous app I was building but in that I was using call receiver but how different can it be?

Comment: how can i use it for screen, for instance? Also, is the code looks fine in general? I am a little lost that why this is happening, any reasons?

Comment: Ok. As I see it no offence but the code is also making me as well a bit confused. Could I suggest a bit simpler way to do this?

Comment: Could you give me some time please? I'll try to give it to you by say tomorrow at max. Since I have some work to do. Sorry

Comment: No problem, I can wait. Thanks,

Comment: Just one more thing do you want it registered in the programming (Complicated) or directly in the Manifest(Simpler) what you have done is the programming method

Comment: @And_Dev Ok I Think I Have Solved It. Check The Above Answer's Edit       This worked on a Samsung Galaxy S5

Comment: Its pretty much the same logic that I have, isn't it? But the problem with your case is that you are using Main Activity to register the receiver. Whereas I am registering it in a service so that the broadcast receiver keeps on running even if Main Activity is not (My service will be running always). Can you explain your point?

Comment: If you want to keep on running a broadcast receiver then it is better to register it or if not I can tell you a way to make it continuously running without using a service. Also you do realize your service keeps multiplying itself every time you run main activity.

Comment: But thats what I believe I am doing. But is this related to my original question?

Comment: Ok. Wait. How about this. Pls. Explain to me what you would like to do in this app. If you want your broadcast receiver to keep running in the baground the best way is to register it into the manifest. However there is another way to achieve the same results programmatically as well. Which do you want to do? Also what I mean is that every time your intent for starting a service is called it again runs your service.  Correct me if I am wrong but services don't shut down that is call onDestroy every time you close the app.

Comment: It keeps on running in the baground also if there are multiple services there are also multiple broadcast receivers thus performing the function of your broadcast receivers multiple times causing frustration to the user and also multiple services cause battery loss as well.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this way:

Define **Receiver** in **manifest** file:

```
<receiver android:name=".ScreenOnOffListener" >
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Now add **class** which **extends** **BroadcastReceiver**:

```
public class ScreenOnOffListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
               Log.i("Check","Screen OFF");
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                Log.i("Check","Screen ON");
            }
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This won't work, you can't register android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF and android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON non programmatically - check the documentation.